# mPDF/ PHP mail like html mail to

Tags: php, email, mailto, mpdf

Im using the follwing code, to attach a generated PDF to a Mail

```
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($html));
$content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$mailto = 'mailto@mailto.com'; //Mailto here
$from_name = 'ACME Corps Ltd'; //Name of sender mail
$from_mail = 'mailfrom@mailfrom.com'; //Mailfrom here
$subject = 'subjecthere';
$message = 'mailmessage';
$filename = "yourfilename-".date("d-m-Y_H-i",time()); //Your Filename whit local date and time

//Headers of PDF and e-mail
$boundary = "XYZ-" . date("dmYis") . "-ZYX";

$header = "--$boundary\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\r\n"; //plain
$header .= "$message\r\n";
$header .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "$content\r\n";
$header .= "--$boundary--\r\n";

$header2 = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header2 .= "From: ".$from_name." \r\n";
$header2 .= "Return-Path: $from_mail\r\n";
$header2 .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
$header2 .= "$boundary\r\n";

mail($mailto,$subject,$header,$header2, "-r".$from_mail);
$mpdf->Output('$filename',);
exit;
```

But i found out, this may be designed for auto-emailing via a PHP-Mailer. But in my case, this should be work like a normal `mailto` link in html, so the message should be prepared and open in Outlook (or a program of your choice) and then you can review it or just click send.

How can this be solved

Answer (score 0):

`mailto:` does not support attachments.

There is a possibility to launch the default email client with parameters, but not to pass attachments.

Comment: Is there any other method?